# How to get rows grouped by with total count (MySQL, Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, eloquent

**Background**

We have this table `lead_activity` in our mysql database, with following fields

```
 1. id
 2. lead_id
 3. activity
```

example of rows:

| id | lead_id | activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | Called |
| 2 | 5 | Selled |
| 3 | 6 | Contacted |
| 4 | 9 | Contacted |

In Laravel, I have got following query:

```
$this->data['lead_activities'] = LeadActivity::select(DB::Raw('count(*) as total'), 'activity')->groupBy('activity')->get();
```

With this result:

```
[
            0 => [
                'total' => 1,
                'activity' => 'Called'
            ],
            1 => [
                'total' => 1,
                'activity' => 'Selled'
            ],
            2 => [
                'total' => 2,
                'activity' => 'Contacted'
            ],
        ]
```

**Request**
How can I build this query (whether Eloquent or raw SQL) so have something similar to these results within just one Query, without any for each after:

```
[
            0 => [
                'total' => 1,
                'activity' => 'Called',
                'lead_ids' => [5]
            ],
            1 => [
                'total' => 1,
                'activity' => 'Selled'
                'lead_ids' => [5],
            ],
            2 => [
                'total' => 2,
                'activity' => 'Contacted',
                'lead_ids' => [6,9]
            ],
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the MySQL GROUP_CONCAT() function.

I think that should solve your problem. Its not returning you an array of lead_ids but a concatenation (string) of all lead_ids, you can work with (transform to array eventually) afterwards.

```
$list = LeadActivity::select(DB::Raw('count(*) as total'), 'activity','GROUP_CONCAT(lead_id) as lead_id_aggr')
        ->groupBy('activity')
        ->get();
```

reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```php
LeadActivity::query()
    ->select(
        'activity',
        DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(lead_id) as leads'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(*) as activities_count'),
    )->groupBy('activity')
    ->get();
```

which would produce this result:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2057
  all: [
    App\Models\LeadActivity {#2059
      activity: "Called",
      leads: "5",
      activities_count: 1,
    },
    App\Models\LeadActivity {#2060
      activity: "Contacted",
      leads: "6,9",
      activities_count: 2,
    },
    App\Models\LeadActivity {#2061
      activity: "Sold",
      leads: "5",
      activities_count: 1,
    },
  ],
}
```